# Use of match within i of data.table

Tags: r, match, data.table

The `%in%` operator is a wrapper for the match function returning "a vector of the same length as x". For instance:

```
> match(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "a"), nomatch = 0) > 0
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

When used within `i` of data.table, however

```
(dt1 <- data.table(v1 = c("a", "b", "c"), v2 = "dt1"))
   v1  v2
1:  a dt1
2:  b dt1
3:  c dt1
(dt2 <- data.table(v1 = c("a", "a"), v2 = "dt2"))
   v1  v2
1:  a dt2
2:  a dt2
dt1[v1 %in% dt2$v1]
   v1  v2
1:  a dt1
2:  a dt1
```

duplicates are obtained. Should the expected behaviour of `%in%` within `i` of data.table not give the same result as

```
dt1[dt1$v1 %in% dt2$v1]  
   v1  v2
1:  a dt1
```

i.e. without duplicates?

Comment: I get it without duplicates using `data.table_1.9.5`

Comment: Yeah, me too. It seems like a bug that was already fixed. BTW, `data.table` has a special method for character matching called `%chin%`, so you could aswell try `dt1[v1 %chin% dt2$v1]`

Comment: I used `data.table_1.9.4` with `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)` on `Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: `dt1[v1 %chin% dt2$v1]` does indeed NOT give duplicates.

Comment: If you want the development version, run `library(devtools); install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot build the package to see if the behavior within the development version is identical: `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'`.

Comment: I'd suggest close all your R sessions and reopen just one, and then run the code above again. Also, I can;t see your comments if you don't use `@`.

Comment: @David Arenburg: I always get the duplicates, even when closing open sessions and re-opening just one. `%chin%` yields the expected behavior without duplicates.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thanks. Did you mean V<1.9.5 and V >= 1.9.5 in your reply, since it seems to be fixed within 1.9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in `data.table` V < 1.9.5 automatic indexing that was fixed in V >= 1.9.5.

I can think of 3 possible workarounds:

1. Disable the auto indexing and use base R `%in%` as in

   ```
   options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
   dt1[v1 %in% dt2$v1]
   ##    v1  v2
   ## 1:  a dt1
   ```
2. Use the built in `%chin%` operator which both more efficient and doesn't have this bug (works only on character vectors comparison)

   ```
   dt1[v1 %chin% dt2$v1]
   ##    v1  v2
   ## 1:  a dt1
   ```
3. Install the development version from Github (Close all your R sessions first and reopen just one)

   ```
   library(devtools)
   install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
   library(data.table)
   dt1 <- data.table(v1 = c("a", "b", "c"), v2 = "dt1")
   dt2 <- data.table(v1 = c("a", "a"), v2 = "dt2")
   dt1[v1 %in% dt2$v1]
   ##    v1  v2
   ## 1:  a dt1
   ```