# data.table: how to filter lines with %in% when not all variables are inside the group?

Tags: r, data.table

This may be a simple question and I am missing something. But It is bugging me. Assume this example data.table:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(group1 = "a", group2 = "z", value  = 1)
```

Why doesn't this work

```
test[group1 %in% c("a", "b"), sum(value), group2]
Erro em `[.data.table`(test, group1 %in% c("a", "b"), sum(value), group2) : 
  i[2] is 0. While grouping, i=0 is allowed when it's the only value. When length(i) > 1, all i should be > 0.
```

But this does:

```
test[group1 %in% c("a", "b"), ][,sum(value), group2]
   group2 V1
1:      z  1
```

Is this really the expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a(nother) *auto-indexing*  bug. Have filed [#1072](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1072). For now, you can disable auto indexing by doing `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. Also, for the future, please add the version of data.table you're working on.

Comment: @Arun thanks for the quick reply!  I am using  `data.table` 1.9.4 .

Comment: @Arun is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411963/use-of-match-within-i-of-data-table/) somewhat related (although it seem to be fixed already)?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it is not related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** This behaviour is fixed in the [development version, 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1072) and works as expected now.

---

Another workaround is to use `data.table` built in `%chin%` function

```
test[group1 %chin% c("a", "b"), sum(value), group2]
#    group2 V1
# 1:      z  1
```

Comment: This a nice workaround, and it may be a little faster than `%in%`.

Comment: It will certainly be, just remember that it is meant for `character` columns only (read documentation). The safest workaround IMO would be @Aruns `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`

Comment: The thing is I am using this inside a package and I don't know if I want to change it and depend on the user keeping this option.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug to me, but you can get your expected behavior with extra parentheses around the `i`:

```
test[(group1 %in% c("a", "b")),sum(value), group2]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simpler than `test[group1 %in% c("a", "b"), ][,sum(value), group2]`.