# R data table select rows to update column

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to update a column for a selection of rows based on the value of the same column. this column contains characters from '1','2',....'10','11'. what I want to do is to combine 11 categories into 3. So my code look like

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(col = as.character(1:11))
DT[col %in% c('1','2','3'), col := '3']
DT[col %in% c('4','5','6','7','8'), col := '2']
DT[col %in% c('9','10','11'), col := '1']
```

weirdly, the last line doesn't work. the '10' and '11' are not updated. when I change 'c' to list (below code), it seems to work. but i don't know why this is the case.

```
DT[col %in% list('9','10','11'), col := '1']
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Bizarrely I am similarly not getting row 10 of DT changed using `DT <- data.table(col=as.character(1:11))` - I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: Works fine for me with thelatemail's input, version 1.9.5 of the package. If you don't want to upgrade to that version, you could develop a habit of putting parentheses around the first arg, like `DT[(col %in% c('9','10','11')), col:= '1']`, which might fix it. There is a known bug in 1.9.4 related to the first arg.

Comment: @Frank - yep, I'm on 1.9.4 here. Seems like a nasty bug so glad it's been sorted.

Comment: thx, putting parentheses does seem work. @frank, do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @Lawrence The developers put in some smart syntax so that when you use `col == y` or `col %in% y` in the first arg, it does data.table magic ("auto indexing") to make that filtering (and future ones on `col`) run faster. Somehow, it didn't work quite right in 1.9.4. It can also be disabled by a setting `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`. Oh, I think I found a dupe with further info (like the `%chin%` function): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932838/1191259

Comment: another way to make it work seem to be turn off the auto index `options(datatable.auto.index= FALSE)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with version 1.11.4 of  `data.table`. So, I am voting to close.